# How to make an event for left & right click at the same time?

Tags: java, user-interface, events, javafx, event-handling

I know how to deal with left or right click separately, dragging, double-clicking, but I can't figure out how to do something if the user clicks left and right mouse buttons at the same time without interfering/causing other events to fire.

```
@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Tile) {
        Tile tile = (Tile) event.getSource();
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)) {
            if (((MouseEvent) event).getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                tile.toggleFlag();
            else if (((MouseEvent) event).getClickCount() == 2)
                mineField.massClick(tile);
        }
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED))
            if (!((MouseEvent) event).getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                tile.startFullDrag();
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED))
            tile.arm();
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_EXITED))
            tile.disarm();
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED))
            mineField.clickedTile(tile);
        if (event.getEventType().equals(ActionEvent.ANY))
            mineField.clickedTile(tile);
    }
}
```

Also, if you see a problem with my code feel free to point it out, always looking to improve.

Answer (score 3):

The simple version is this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {

                if( e.isPrimaryButtonDown() && e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    System.out.println( "Both down");
                } else if( e.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    System.out.println( "Primary down");
                } else if( e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    System.out.println( "Secondary down");
                }

            });

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you prefer your own event happening when both buttons are pressed, you could try it this way:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    BooleanProperty primaryMouseButtonDown = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    BooleanProperty secondaryMouseButtonDown = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
                primaryMouseButtonDown.setValue( e.isPrimaryButtonDown());
                secondaryMouseButtonDown.setValue( e.isSecondaryButtonDown());
            });

            root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
                primaryMouseButtonDown.setValue( e.isPrimaryButtonDown());
                secondaryMouseButtonDown.setValue( e.isSecondaryButtonDown());
            });

            BooleanBinding binding = Bindings.and(primaryMouseButtonDown, secondaryMouseButtonDown);
            binding.addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    System.out.println( "Mouse Button Event: " + oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
                }
            });


            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are 2 boolean properties, one for the primary button down and one for the secondary button down. Both properties are connected via a BooleanBinding. Whenever one of the properties change via the mouse event, an event is fired. So what's left to do is for you to check if newValue is true and fire your handling code.

Answer (score 1):

Do something more along the lines of, watch for mouse presses, and set a boolean to true when a mousePressed event is called for left/right mouse button. Then later in the event look to see if both booleans for left and right are true. If they are, act on it as if both were pressed at the same time.

```
boolean mouse_1, mouse_2 = false;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    //The numbers are just made up I don't remember the actual codes for the buttons but it's simple enough to figure out.
    if(e.getButton()==1){
        mouse_1  = true;
    }
    if(e.getButton()==2){
        mouse_2  = true;
    }

    if(mouse_1&&mouse_2){
    //Your code here
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getButton() == 1){
        mouse_1 = false;
    }
    if(e.getButton() == 2){
        mouse_2 = false;
    }
}
```

Assume this is some sort of handler class... But this is the short for how to implement it.

Comment: Are these boolean values class fields? Otherwise it wouldn't work right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't define them in the answer I thought it was apparent that they were pre-initialized somewhere higher up.. Let me edit my answer @jpdemko

Comment: @TheJavaCoder16 Can you convert this AWT code to JavaFX code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably late to answer this question, but I'm going to post my solution in order to demonstrate how to handle single-button clicks separately from both buttons being clicked at the same time

Existing answers already explained how to detect both mouse buttons being clicked at the same time. But mouse events (click, press, and release) are still triggered by individual buttons and previous posters didn't address how to avoid these events from interfering with each other.

My solution is to track both buttons being pressed on mouse press and detect mouse clicks of any kind on mouse release:

```
//flag to track both buttons being pressed
private boolean wereBothButtonsPressed = false;

private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //single button press sets flag to false
    wereBothButtonsPressed = e.isPrimaryButtonDown() && e.isSecondaryButtonDown();
}

private void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown() || e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
        //do nothing if user is still holding the button
        return;
    }
    if (wereBothButtonsPressed) {
        System.out.prinln("Both buttons");
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        System.out.prinln("Only primary");
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        System.out.prinln("Only secondary");
    }
}
```

You can set these handlers for specific events on specific controls or fit them into your method:

```
private boolean wereBothButtonsPressed = false;

@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
    ...

    if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) event;
        wereBothButtonsPressed = me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && me.isSecondaryButtonDown();
    } else if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)) {
        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) event;
        if (!me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && !me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
            if(wereBothButtonsPressed) {
                mineField.massClick(tile);
            } else if(me.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                mineField.clickedTile(tile);
            } else if(me.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                tile.toggleFlag();
            }
        } 
    ...
```